# php arrays - not getting expected output

Tags: php, arrays

I have a piece of code that is supposed to grab categories, sort them alphabetically (they're available in several languages) as well as return a count for each of them. The problem is, for some reason the count isn't returned at all. I feel like the problem is somewhere around this line:

```
(($categoryCounter) ? '<span class="cnt">(' . $categoryCounter . ')</span>' : '') .
```

I tried changing it to $categoryCounter[$key] or something but that didn't work. Unfortunately my PHP skills are not good enough to find out what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can see what I'm obviously doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate some help :)

Here is the complete code;

```
while ($cat_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_categories)) 
{
    $categoryCounter = (COUNT_CATS == 1 && !empty($src_details['keywords_search'])) ? $cat_counter[$cat_details['category_id']] : $cat_details['items_counter'];
    if ($categoryCounter > 0 || COUNT_CATS == 0) {
        $cat_array[$cat_details['category_id']]["name"]=$category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']];
    }
}

if (is_array($cat_array)) {

    asort($cat_array);

    foreach($cat_array as $key => $value){

        $output .= '<tr> '.
        '   <td class="contentfont"><a href="' . $subcat_link . '">' . $category_lang[$key] . '</a> '.
        (($categoryCounter) ? '<span class="cnt">(' . $categoryCounter . ')</span>' : '') .
    ' </td> '.
    '</tr> ';

    }
}
```

Comment: One part you do wrong is the way how you word the title of your question.

Comment: Try to echo the value of `$categoryCounter` before the for loop or the if statement, to see what value it holds? Do a simple debug run.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us the problem. What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @hakre: sorry, i wasn't really sure how to word it.

Comment: i get no error message at all. the part of the $categoryCounter where it's supposed to display a number it just shows up nothing.

Comment: a var_dump($categoryCounter); shows string(1) "0" below the asort

Comment: Again: Try to echo the value of $categoryCounter before the for loop or the if statement, to see what value it holds? Do a simple debug run.

Answer (score 0):

If `$categoryCounter` is `"0"`, then the condition `($categoryCounter)` will be false, so you with your posted code, an empty string will be outputted, instead of the `<span` tag you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be the entire code as a few things aren't defined.  Why does COUNT_CATS not start with a $?  What is the layout of the $cat_array object?  Are there multiple columns or is "name" the only column?

First up, try adding the $ to the front of these:

```
$COUNT_CATS == 1
$COUNT_CATS == 0
```

From what I can tell from what you provided, $categoryCounter will be the highest value from your loop starting with:

```
while ($cat_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_categories))
```

But currently you may not ever set the $cat_array as $categoryCounter may never be anything other than 0, and COUNT_CATS may or may not be valid.

Also, the $cat_array object could be assigned without the ["name"] part, i.e.

```
$cat_array[$cat_details['category_id']]=$category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']];
```

This would then have $cat_array[id]=$category_lang[id], which would then be sorted fine via the asort function.  $cat_array[id]["name"]=$category_lang[id] would be sorted differently as it is now a multi-dimensional array.